# Using lodash, how do I set multiple properties on an object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a list of properties, like so:

```
const list = [
  'creditCardNumber',
  'orderDetails.amount',
  'customerInformation.details.email',
]
```

Given an object like this:

```
const someObj = {
  creditCardNumber: '000 0000 0000 0000',
  orderNumber: '1234',
  orderDetails: { amount: 20, date: 'some date' },
  customerInformation: { details: { email: 'some@email.com', joinedOn: 'someDate' } },
  someOtherProp: 'some value',
}
```

Using `lodash`, or vanilla JS, is there an easy way to make a copy of the obj, while re-writing the values of locations on the `list` array (to the same value for eg: `[HIDDEN]`) so we get something like this?

```
{  
  const someObj = {
  creditCardNumber: '[HIDDEN]',
  orderNumber: '1234',
  orderDetails: { amount:'[HIDDEN]', date: 'some date' },
  customerInformation: { details: { email: '[HIDDEN]', joinedOn: 'someDate' } },
  someOtherProp: 'some value',
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) accepts dot seperated object paths, so

```js
_.set(obj, 'orderDetails.amount', 'TEST');
```

Will resolve to:

```js
obj.orderDetails.amount = 'TEST'
```

Combine that with a loop for each `list` item to get the desired result:

```js
const list = [ 'creditCardNumber', 'orderDetails.amount', 'customerInformation.details.email' ];
const someObj = {creditCardNumber: '000 0000 0000 0000', orderNumber: '1234', orderDetails: { amount: 20, date: 'some date' }, customerInformation: { details: { email: 'some@email.com', joinedOn: 'someDate' } }, someOtherProp: 'some value', }

const newObj = _.clone(someObj);
list.forEach(key => _.set(newObj, key, '[HIDDEN]'));
console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

```json
{
    "creditCardNumber": "[HIDDEN]",
    "orderNumber": "1234",
    "orderDetails":
    {
        "amount": "[HIDDEN]",
        "date": "some date"
    },
    "customerInformation":
    {
        "details":
        {
            "email": "[HIDDEN]",
            "joinedOn": "someDate"
        }
    },
    "someOtherProp": "some value"
}
```

**Note:** Using [`_.clone()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#clone) to 'clone' the object ;)

Answer (score 0):

**USING VANILLA JS**

Clone object using [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and then using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) add the `[HIDDEN]` value

```js
const list = [
  "creditCardNumber",
  "orderDetails.amount",
  "customerInformation.details.email",
];

const someObj = {
  creditCardNumber: "000 0000 0000 0000",
  orderNumber: "1234",
  orderDetails: {
    amount: 20,
    date: "some date"
  },
  customerInformation: {
    details: {
      email: "some@email.com",
      joinedOn: "someDate"
    },
  },
  someOtherProp: "some value",
};

let clone = { ...someObj };

list.forEach((prop) => {
  const splitProp = prop.split(".");

  let obj = clone;
  splitProp.forEach((p, i, arr) => {
    if (i === arr.length - 1) {
      obj[p] = `[HIDDEN]`;
    } else {
      obj = obj[p];
    }
  });
});

console.log(clone);
```

Comment: Thanks! but `amount` and `email` aren't set to `[HIDDEN]` in your code snippet

Comment: @nkhil I come up with one more solution with vanilla JS